# Get List Template ID JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-template

I have some code that returns all of the lists in my site however I need to only get lists that are using the discussion board template and I have hit a stumbling block with this.

I currently have the following:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', PreSaveAction);

function PreSaveAction() {

    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    lists = web.get_lists();

    context.load(lists);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Succeeded, Failed);


    function Succeeded() {

        var listItemEnumerator;

        listItemEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            var listname = oListItem.get_title();
        }
    }

    function Failed(sender, args) {
        console.log("Failed" + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

}
```

I have tried a few different approaches but so far had no luck, I know that the list template `ID` is `108` and I have tried to use this to return the list I need but unfortunately I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know the `BaseTemplate` of discussion board, so you can apply `$filter` in your all lists

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 108
```

Make a GET request to the above **URL**, It will return all lists those are using discussion board template.

## Example using jQuery

```
function getDiscussionBoardList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 108',
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.d.results); // all discussion board lists are here
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

## Using JSOM

In your code, you can apply some filter in `Succeeded()` callback. Meaning `oListItem.get_baseTemplate() == 108`

```
function Succeeded() {

    var listItemEnumerator;

    listItemEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    var discussionBoardLists = [];

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        if (oListItem.get_baseTemplate() == 108) {
            var listname = oListItem.get_title();
            discussionBoardLists.push(listname);
        }
    }

    // all discussion board list.
    console.log(discussionBoardLists);
}
```

In **JSOM**, you need to load all lists which unnecessary. In that case **REST API** is the best.

If you do not have jQuery, then you can use pure javascript [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 108');

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); // all discussion lists
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText)
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.send();
```

So my recommendation is *Only* **REST API** for this requirement.