# How can I know what kind of App I am in?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, custom-list, task-list

Is there a way for a user to find out what kind of app she/he is using once already inside? Say a SharePoint 2013 user is inside of a Custom List. 
How would this user know if she was using a Custom List instead of a Task List?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you open an ítem with Display Form you can find the section "**Content Type: Task**" just above created and modifided data.

Comment: I don't think that's really reliable.  What if you create a custom list and add the Task content type to it, then create an item of type Task?

Comment: Good point ....

Comment: What do you mean by the word legend?

Answer (score 0):

There is way to find programtically, you can get list object and use below method to get base template id...

```
oListItem.get_baseTemplate()
```

Refer below link for your detailed reference...

[Get List Template ID JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166350/get-list-template-id-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no this is only displayed from what sort of tile an app gets before you are go into it.

I would inform the users that they can review this on the site contents page to learn about what sort of app was used to create the list/library they are using. The ribbon options can also be a clue to users if there in a list or library but they type isn't easy to figure out without looking at the tile.

App Tile Examples: 
From left to right: Custom list, Document Library, Calendar, Links list, Task List, Discussion board. (etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it from `ctx`. I believe you are familiar with `ctx`. If you are not familiar with `ctx`, then have a look over [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165827/21421). Now write few lines of code and it to you master page.

```
(function () {

    // Al list templates
    var listTemplates = [{
        "name": "Document Library",
        "listTemplate": 101
    }, {
        "name": "Form Library",
        "listTemplate": 115
    }, {
        "name": "Wiki Page Library",
        "listTemplate": 119
    }, {
        "name": "Picture Library",
        "listTemplate": 109
    }, {
        "name": "Links",
        "listTemplate": 103
    }, {
        "name": "Announcements",
        "listTemplate": 104
    }, {
        "name": "Contacts",
        "listTemplate": 105
    }, {
        "name": "Calendar",
        "listTemplate": 106
    }, {
        "name": "Promoted Links",
        "listTemplate": 170
    }, {
        "name": "Discussion Board",
        "listTemplate": 108
    }, {
        "name": "Tasks",
        "listTemplate": 171
    }, {
        "name": "Issue Tracking",
        "listTemplate": 1100
    }, {
        "name": "Custom List",
        "listTemplate": 100
    }, {
        "name": "Custom List in Datasheet View",
        "listTemplate": 120
    }, {
        "name": "External List",
        "listTemplate": 600
    }, {
        "name": "Survey",
        "listTemplate": 102
    }, {
        "name": "Asset Library",
        "listTemplate": 851
    }, {
        "name": "Data Connection Library",
        "listTemplate": 130
    }, {
        "name": "Report Library",
        "listTemplate": 433
    }, {
        "name": "Access App",
        "listTemplate": 3100
    }];

    // find current list 

    var currentList = listTemplates.find(function (item) {
        return item.listTemplate == ctx.listTemplate;
    });

    if (currentList) {
        alert(currentList.name);
    } else {
        alert("Unable to find.");
    }
})();
```

`ctx.listTemplate` returns the current list's template. `listTemplates` has all lists name & template information. So I am just finding current list's information based on `ctx.listTemplate`.

Find all list templates in *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx)*.